# Can I install a theme meant for Linux Mint[cinnamon] on Ubuntu?

Tags: unity, themes, cinnamon

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 on my system.

The other day I found this cool theme meant for the cinnamon desktop and downloaded the zip file of that theme. I extracted it to `/usr/share/themes` but I couldn't find it on unity-tweak tool or ubuntu-tweak.

I also tried to install it using the 'install theme' option in Ubuntu-tweak, but it said it's an invalid theme file.

Is there any way to make this work? Or do I need a cinnamon desktop to install that theme?

Answer (score 0):

I think themes are generally very specific to the window manager it's made for, you might be able to take the theme "apart" and make a new theme for ubuntu/unity using the same images & colors?

Or it's probably easier to try installing cinnamon on ubuntu? Search for `install cinnamon ubuntu 14.04` and there are a lot of pages saying how to do it.

Comment: Hmm, yes I think I would have to make a new theme if I wanted to keep my Unity. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: There should be an easy way to do it, may be some cool theme program that can make themes for multiple desktops, but I haven't seen one. I don't use unity or gnome3, but it always seems like the coolest themes are for some other desktop ;-)

Comment: Hmm.. that's a nice idea. I'll search for that. But if I don't get it I think I have to write my own CSS file.. :/ but I have the CSS file in that theme so I guess I'll just edit it to fit the gtk syntax